# Ansible: Assign multiple EIPs to each new secondary private IPs in an ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

today I am trying to assign multiple elastic IPs to multiple different private IP addresses.

NOTE: IP addresses are fake, I've wrote them like this to make you understand what I'd like to do.

**This is what I have achieved so far:**

```
Server 1

  Elastic Network Interface
    Private IP 172.x.x.1 (public IP: 55.x.x.1)
    Secondary Private IP 
      172.x.x.2 (public IP: NONE SET)
      172.x.x.3 (public IP: NONE SET)

Server 2

  Elastic Network Interface
    Private IP 174.x.x.1 (public IP: 57.x.x.1)
    Secondary Private IP 
      174.x.x.2 (public IP: NONE SET)
      174.x.x.3 (public IP: NONE SET)
```

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**

```
Server 1

  Elastic Network Interface
    Private IP 172.x.x.1 (public IP: 55.x.x.1)
    Secondary Private IP 
      172.x.x.2 (public IP: 55.x.x.2)
      172.x.x.3 (public IP: 55.x.x.3)

Server 2

  Elastic Network Interface
    Private IP 174.x.x.1 (public IP: 57.x.x.1)
    Secondary Private IP 
      174.x.x.2 (public IP: 57.x.x.2)
      174.x.x.3 (public IP: 57.x.x.3)
```

**Here's the Ansible playbook I wrote so far:**

`{{ platform }}` is an extra var passed through CLI.

```
- name: Provision a set of Edge instances
  ec2:
     key_name: ec2user
     group: "launch-wizard-1"
     instance_type: "m4.2xlarge"
     image: "ami-xxxxxxx"
     region: "eu-west-1"
     wait: true
     exact_count: 2
     count_tag:
        PlatformName: "{{ platform }}"
        Role: Edge
     instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ platform }}::Edge"
        PlatformName: "{{ platform }}"
        Role: Edge
        LongName: "Edge server for {{ platform }}'s platform"
        Groups: common,server,rabbitmq,memcache,stats,cache-manager,media,content,icecast
  register: edge_ec2

- name: Find ENIs created for Edge instances
  ec2_eni_facts:
    region: "eu-west-1"
    filters:
      attachment.instance-id: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ edge_ec2.instance_ids }}"  
  register: edge_enis

- name: Adds an additional private IP to the Edge ENIs
  ec2_eni:
    region: "eu-west-1"
    eni_id: "{{ item.interfaces[0].id }}"
    subnet_id: "{{ item.interfaces[0].subnet_id }}"
    state: present
    secondary_private_ip_address_count: 2
  register: created_ips
  with_items: "{{ edge_enis.results }}"

- name: Adds additional elastic IPs to the Edge ENIs
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: "{{ item.0.interface.attachment.instance_id }}"
    region: "eu-west-1"
    private_ip_address: "{{ item.1.private_ip_address }}"
    in_vpc: true
  register: eips
  with_subelements: 
    - "{{ created_ips.results }}"
    - interface.private_ip_addresses
```

Why doesn't ansible assign the new allocated elastic IPs to the secondary private IPs, but only to the primary one, even though I specifically tell to assign it to the secondary private IPs?

Comment: Can not find any question in your posting.

Comment: added the question, sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Ansible [ec2_eip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_eip_module.html) module fails to create a new elastic IP and assign it to the specified secondary private IP address, but I did discover a workaround.

I experienced the same problem — it seemed to me that the `private_ip_address` option was being ignored. Here's a snippet of my code that didn't work:

```
- name: try to create an EIP and associate it in one pass
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: "{{ item.network_interfaces[0].network_interface_id }}"
    private_ip_address: "{{ item.network_interfaces[0].private_ip_addresses[1].private_ip_address }}"
    region: ap-southeast-2
    in_vpc: true 
  with_items: "{{ servers.results[0].instances }}"
```

My workaround was to pre-create the elastic IPs and then associate them with the private IPs in a separate task.

```
- name: "allocate a new elastic IP for each server without associating it with anything"
  ec2_eip:
    state: 'present'
    region: ap-southeast-2
  register: eip2
  with_items: "{{ servers.results[0].instances }}" 

- name: Associate elastic IPs with the first interface attached to each instance
  ec2_eip:
    public_ip: "{{ eip2.results[item.0].public_ip }}"
    device_id: "{{ item.1.network_interfaces[0].network_interface_id }}"
    private_ip_address: "{{ item.1.network_interfaces[0].private_ip_addresses[1].private_ip_address }}"
    region: ap-southeast-2
    in_vpc: true 
  with_indexed_items: "{{ servers.results[0].instances }}"
```

My key finding was that if you supply `public_ip` then the `private_ip_address` option starts being recognised.